# Connection to MQTT Broker

Tags: java, mqtt, broker

I need to realize connection to broker. Now I'm connecting to public broker in the Internet (`http://www.mqtt-dashboard.com/`). I do it in the following way:

```
 private static final String broker = "tcp://broker.mqttdashboard.com:1883"; //bridge and host
 mqttClient = new MqttClient(broker, MqttClient.generateClientId(), new MemoryPersistence());  //URI, ClientId, Persistence
 mqttClient.connect();
```

But how can I connect to the broker which I downloaded and which is on my computer?  Tried to change `tcp://broker.mqttdashboard.com` on path to broker (such as `E:\MQTT\rsmb_1.2.0_MQTT\windows\broker.exe`), but it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a broker is like a server, so you need to download the tool and configure the port on it, 
after that you can launch it and connect to to it using something like  "tcp://localhost:1883" as a network setting...

Or like @hardillb said

"mqtt://localhost:1883"

Answer (score 0):

It's a TCP port, not an executable.

If it's on your local machine, then `tcp://127.0.0.1:1883`